Can I use a subquery inside of decode()?
Given this expression:
DECODE(SUBSTR(T.CARD_NUMBER, 1, 1),
       '4',
       'VISA',
       '2',
       'MasterCard',
       T.SCHEME)

Is it allowed to use a subquery that fetches values from a table instead of the constants?

Just use LEFT JOIN?

This question sounds like it's caused by an XY problem. It would likely be far better if you show some sample data and the expected result and explain why your current query doesn't produce it.

Max one row only, one column only.

DECODE function expects a minimum of three arguments - expr, search, result.
If you ask is it allowed to fetch the arguments (plural) using subquery the answer is NO - cause function expects three arguments. It is possible to fetch an argument using a subquery and another using second subquery, though, but that would be senseless. It would be something like this:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    cards AS
      ( Select '2222 3333 4444 5555' as card_number, 'MasterCard' as card_name From Dual Union All 
        Select '4444 5555 6666 7777', 'Visa' From Dual 
      ),
    cards_balance AS
      ( Select '2222 3333 4444 5555' as card_number, 100 as balance From Dual Union All 
        Select '4444 5555 6666 7777', 200 From Dual
      )

--      S Q L : 
Select  cb.card_number,
        Decode( SubStr(cb.card_number, 1, 1 ),
                ( Select SubStr(card_number, 1, 1) From cards  Where card_number = cb.card_number ), 
                ( Select card_name From cards  Where card_number = cb.card_number ),
                'N/A'
              ) as card_name,
        cb.balance
From    cards_balance cb




CARD_NUMBER
CARD_NAME
BALANCE




2222 3333 4444 5555
MasterCard
100


4444 5555 6666 7777
Visa
200



The same result could be fetched simply using the code below:
Select  cb.card_number, c.card_name, cb.balance
From    cards_balance cb
Left Join cards c ON( c.card_number = cb.card_number )

See the fiddle here.
